# Log4J2 is not printing message from Log.info()

Tags: java, logs

While writing the below code, no message is being printed on the console for logger.debug(), and logger.info() methods.

```
package log4j2.test;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

public class Test {
    public static void main(final String... args) 
    {
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Test.class);
        logger.debug("Debug Message Logged !!!");
        logger.info("Info Message Logged !!!");
        logger.fatal("Fatal Message Logged !!!");
        logger.error("Error Message Logged !!!", new NullPointerException("NullError"));
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
14:04:11.173 [main] FATAL log4j2.test.Test - Fatal Message Logged !!!
14:04:11.176 [main] ERROR log4j2.test.Test - Error Message Logged !!!
java.lang.NullPointerException: NullError
    at log4j2.test.Test.main(Test.java:15) [test-classes/:?]
```

log4j2.properties:

```
status = warn
name = ConsoleLogConfigDemo

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = consoleLogger
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = consoleLogger
```

I have also tried the same with log4j2.xml. Below is the xml file content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" strict="true">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p method: [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
        </Console>

        <Appender type="File" name="file" fileName="Logs\app.log">
            <Layout type="PatternLayout"
                pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t]%-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Appender>
    </Appenders>


    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="file" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score -1):

On your log4j.properties file, you can set the log level for a package:

```
log4j.logger.log4j2.test=debug
```